# Definition of starred commands with `csname`

Tags: macros, strings, starred-version, csname

I want to define a command, let's call it `\commander`, for defining starred and non-starred versions of a new command. `\commander` would be called as follows:

```
\commander[<options>]{\thenewcommand}
```

This creates the commands `\thenewcommand` and `\thenewcommand*`, with slightly different instructions. (The specific definitions of those commands are of no importance for this question. I've already worked them out.) The way I tried to define `\commander` depends on a one-argument command called `\commandname`, which returns the string of the name of a command, but without its backslash. For example:

1. `\commandname{\empty}` returns the string `empty`
2. `\commandname{\color}` returns the string `color`
3. `\commandname{\thenewcommand}` returns the string `thenewcommand`
4. And so forth...

I don't think that there's any problem with `\commandname` since it has worked perfectly up until my attempt of defining `\commander`. But just in case, here is its definition:

```
\newcommand{\commandname}[1]{%
  \ifcat\relax\noexpand#1%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
  \@gobble\expandafter\string\fi#1}
```

(This was poposed by [Ashok](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454641).)

Any suggestion for improving or simplifying this `\commandname` is welcome.

`\commander` is then defined roughly as follows:

```
\newcommand{\commander}[2][]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand{#2}{%
    \@ifstar%
      \csname star\commandname{#2}\endcsname%
      \csname nostar\commandname{#2}\endcsname}%
  %
  %DEFINE THE #2 COMMAND
  \expandafter\newcommand{\csname nostar\commandname{#2}\endcsname}%
    {<code for #2>}
  %
  %DEFINE THE #2* COMMAND
  \expandafter\newcommand{\csname star\commandname{#2}\endcsname}%
    {<code for #2*>}%
}
```

But whenever I attempt to call  `\commander`, it returns the following error messages:

```
Command \csname already defined. \commander{\thenewcommand}
Extra \endcsname. \commander{\thenewcommand}
```

I have previously used a similar structure for recursively defining commands, so I suppose the problem is in the simultaneous use of `\@ifstar` and `\csname`.

I would strongly prefer that the solution be as TeX primitive as possible because I would like to use it in several projects. In my current project, though, I am using the packages `everypage` and `pgf/tikz`. So a solution depending on those packages is also welcome.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what happens if you embrace `{}` the `\csname...\endcsname` star options?

Comment: Thanks @StevenB.Segletes. I've just tried it, but no difference: the same error messages.

Comment: You need an extra `\expandafter`: `\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname nostar\commandname{#2}\endcsname}{<code for #2>}`.  Otherwise, you are only epanding the `{`

Comment: This seems related: [Removing a backslash from a character sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42318/5764)

Comment: Thanks, @StevenB.Segletes. That almost did it, but I still have the following error message: `Command \starthecommand already defined. \commander{\thecommand}`.

If I try instead `\expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter{\csname nostar\commandname{#2}\endcsname}{<code for #2>}`, it returns the message `\starthecommand undefined. \commander{\thecommand}`.

Comment: Your question (as true for most questions) would be much easier to answer if you provided a small complete document that produces the error rather than just posting disconnected fragments.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidCarlisle. I tend to post very abbreviated versions of my commands, because they often depend on several others that I made. Hence, the production of a small complete document becomes difficult considering the original file is much longer. However, I will seriously consider your suggestion since some answers to previous questions I posted made me feel a concern in the direction you're pointing.

Comment: if you don't provide a test file you force anyone answering to guess how to put the fragments together and make their own test file as  Skillmon had to do here, but that makes answering harder and if the guess is wrong the effort is wasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to extract the name without the backslash for the `\csname`. You could use something like the following:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\commander[2][]
  {%
    \@ifdefinable#2%
      {%
        \protected\edef#2%
          {%
            \noexpand\@ifstar
              \expandafter\noexpand\csname\string#2star\endcsname
              \expandafter\noexpand\csname\string#2nostar\endcsname
          }%
        \expandafter\newcommand\csname\string#2star\endcsname{.star.}%
        \expandafter\newcommand\csname\string#2nostar\endcsname{no.star.}%
      }%
  }
\makeatother

\commander\thecommand

\begin{document}
\thecommand

\thecommand*
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Skillmon. What is the `\@ifdefinable`conditional for?

Comment: @lfba checks whether the macro is already defined, if it is, it throws an error just as `\newcommand` would. If it isn't the second argument is executed. I then use `\protected\edef` instead of `\newcommand` so that the `\csname`s are only evaluated once and not on every call, also the macro has to be robust (hence the `\protected`), as `\@ifstar` isn't expandable.

Comment: @lfba if you used `\newcommand` or `\def` instead of `\edef` you'd have to use braces around the `\csname`s after the `\@ifstar`, and you wouldn't need `\expandafter\noexpand` before the `\csname`s.

Comment: Thanks, @Skillmon. It has been very instructive.

Comment: Please let me ask one more question, @Skillmon. Is there a way to use `\string` outside `\csname ... \endcsname`?

Comment: @lfba `\string` can be used anywhere. Just try `\string\foo` in the document body (you'll need to use `\texttt{\string\foo}` for the backslash to be printed as such).

Answer (score 3):

```
  \expandafter\newcommand{\csname nostar\commandname{#2}\endcsname}%
```

applies `\expandafter` to `{` which is a non-expandable token.

You intended

```
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname nostar\commandname{#2}\endcsname
```

to apply `\expandafter` to `\csname`.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> \newcommand{\commandname}[1]{%
>   \ifcat\relax\noexpand#1%
>   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
>   \@gobble\expandafter\string\fi#1}
> ```
>
> Any suggestion for improving or simplifying this `\commandname` is welcome.

You asked, so let's do some nitpicking:    ;-)

Your routine `\commandname` seems to be intended to do the following things:

Detect whether the argument consists of a single `⟨control sequence token⟩`.
If so, apply `\string` and remove the leading backslash from the result for obtaining something that can be "fed" to `\csname`..`\endcsname`.
If not so, take the token sequence which forms the argument for something that can be "fed" to `\csname`..`\endcsname`.

## Issue 1:

There are some edge-cases:

How to handle, e.g., the situation that one wishes to define a macro `\SantaClaus` from macro `\Santa` and macro `\CLaus` while `\Santa` is defined as `\def\Santa{Santa}` and `\Claus` is defined as `\def\Claus{Claus}`?

In this scenario, one could do `\expandafter\edef\csname\Santa\Claus\endcsname{\Santa\noexpand\nobreak\ \Claus}`.

The crucial point here is: You can "feed" macros to `\csname`. Expandable tokens will be expanded while (La)TeX searches the matching `\endcsname`.

Let's look at `\commandname{\Santa\Claus}`—this yields:

```
\ifcat\relax\noexpand\Santa\Claus
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\@gobble\expandafter\string\fi\Santa\Claus
```

→

```
\Claus Santa\Claus
```

I suppose, this is not intended.

## Issue 2:

`\commandname` may fail with control sequences that are implicit character tokens:

E.g., try

```
\let\CmdCharA=A
\commandname{\CmdCharA}
```

The problem is:

Here `\CmdCharA` has the meaning of the character token `A` whose category code is 11(letter) and whose character code is 65.

Therefore the `\ifcat`-check will yield that `\CmdCharA`'s catcode (which is 11(letter)) will differ from what by `\ifcat` internally is taken for the catcode of the `\relax`-primitive.

Therefore stringification and gobbling will not take place.

## Issue 3:

In TeX there is an integer-parameter `\escapechar` which denotes the number of the code point in the TeX engine's internal encoding of the chacter which shall be prepended in case `\string` delivers the name of a `⟨control sequence token⟩`.  Usually the value of `\escapechar` is 92. 92 is the number of the code point of the backslash character both in ASCII-encoding and in Unicode while the internal encoding with traditional TeX engines is ASCII and with XeTeX- or LuaTeX-based TeX engines is Unicode. In case the value of `\escapechar` is negative, no character will be prepended at all. In case the value of `\escapechar` is greater than the largest code point number which is possible in the TeX engine's internal encoding, the situation is as follows: With traditional TeX engines no character will be prepended. With most recent XeTeX- or LuaTeX-based engines no character will be prepended. With LuaTeX-based engines prior to  luatex 1.10.0, you can get unexpected results. (See, e.g., my question [\string-primitive works in unexpected ways in LuaTeX — Where can I find exact documentation of the \string-primitive in LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437465/118714)  and David Carlisle's answer to that question.)

Try e.g.,

```
\newlinechar=`^^J
\escapechar=92 %
\def\stringifyrelaxwithescapechar#1{%
  \message{^^J^^J}%
  \message{When \string\escapechar=\number#1, then (\string\string\string\relax) yields:}%
  \escapechar=#1\relax
  \message{(\string\relax)}%
  \escapechar=92 %
}%
\message{^^J^^J}%
\message{The great \string\string\space and \string\escapechar\space test:}%
\message{^^J}%
\message{=======================================}%
\stringifyrelaxwithescapechar{92}%
\stringifyrelaxwithescapechar{`\A}%
\stringifyrelaxwithescapechar{`\B}%
\stringifyrelaxwithescapechar{`\C}%
\stringifyrelaxwithescapechar{`\Z}%
\stringifyrelaxwithescapechar{`\7}%
\stringifyrelaxwithescapechar{`\/}%
\stringifyrelaxwithescapechar{`\?}%
\stringifyrelaxwithescapechar{`\:}%
\stringifyrelaxwithescapechar{-1}%
\stringifyrelaxwithescapechar{32}%
\message{^^J^^J}%
\csname stop\endcsname
\bye
```

By the way: Character tokens delivered due to `\string` usually have the category code 12(other). An exception is the space character. If `\string` delivers a space character token, that token will have category code 10(space), i.e., it will be a space token. When the value of `\escapechar` is 32, then applying `\string` to a `⟨control sequence token⟩` yields a token sequence with a leading space token. You cannot have that space token removed via `\@gobble` because `\@gobble` will process/remove the following **non-delimited argument** while (La)TeX silently discards space tokens while searching the very first token that belongs to a non-delimited argument. Therefore in this edge case the leading space and the following non-space-character would be removed.

Summa summarum: When applying `\string` you may need to take the value of `\escapechar` into account when deciding whether a leading backslash (or whatever) needs to be removed.

## I suggest a different approach:

As the mechanism is intended for defining macros, there is no need for it to work in pure-expansion-contexts as well.

Thus you can temporarily assign, e.g., the value 92 (92 is the code-point number of the backslash-character in (La)TeX's internal encoding) to `\escapechar`.

Besides this, don't let the mechanism try to find out whether the user specified a `⟨control sequence token⟩` or a token sequence that needs to be "fed" to `\csname`..`\endcsname` but let the users specify that themselves.

I sometimes use a macro `\name` which processes an argument which is delimited by a left curly brace (`{`) and an argument which is nested in braces.
The argument nested in braces is taken for the name of a `⟨control sequence token⟩` which is to be constructed via `\csname`..`\endcsname`. In the `⟨parameter text⟩` of a macro-definition you can use `#{`-notation for a macro whose last argument will be delimited by a `{` which will (unlike other argument-delimiters) be left in place/be re-insered:

```
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\name{\long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\innername{#1}}}%
\newcommand\innername[2]{\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}}%
```

Some usage-examples:

`\name{foo}` → `\foo`
`\name\string{foo}` → `\string\foo`
`\name\meaing{foo}` → `\meaning\foo`
`\name\global\long\def{foo}...` → `\global\long\def\foo...`
`\name\newcommand*{foo}...` → `\newcommand*\foo...`
`\name\name\global\let{foo}={bar}` → `\name\global\let\foo={bar}`  → `\global\let\foo=\bar`

Putting the pieces together, assuming that the "starred" form of the command shall always process the same set of arguments/shall (apart from the star) have the same `⟨parameter text⟩` as the "non-starred" form, I would probably do something like this:

```
\makeatletter

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\name{\long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\innername{#1}}}%
\newcommand\innername[2]{\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}}%

% \myUnexpandableStringifier{<tokens to prepend after stringification>}%
%                           {<control sequence token to stringify>}%
% ->
% <tokens to prepend after stringification>{<stringified control sequence token without leading escapechar>}
\newcommand\myUnexpandableStringifier[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \escapechar=92 %
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\exchange
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\@gobble\string#2}}{\endgroup#1}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\commander{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\commander[1]{%
     \myUnexpandableStringifier{\innercommander}{#1}%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\innercommander{%
  \long\def\innercommander#1#2#{%
    % #1 = <name of control sequence>
    % #2 = <(same) parameter-text both for starred variant and non-starred variant>
    \name\name\name\innerinnercommander{#1}{#1atnostar}{#1atstar}{#2}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\innerinnercommander[6]{%
   % #1 = <control sequence>
   % #2 = <control sequence at nostar>
   % #3 = <control sequence at star>
   % #4 = <(same) parameter-text both for starred variant and non-starred variant>
   % #5 = <<balanced text> of the <definition text> of the unstarred definition>
   % #6 = <<balanced text> of the <definition text> of the starred definition>
  \@ifdefinable{#1}{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand*#1{\@ifstar{#3}{#2}}%
    \newcommand#2#4{#5}%
    \newcommand#3#4{#6}%
  }%
}%

\commander\Foo[3][optional]{%
  This is Foo-without-star's optional argument: #1%
  This is Foo-without-star's first non-optional argument: #2%
  This is Foo-without-star's second non-optional argument: #3%
}{%
  This is Foo-with-star's optional argument: #1%
  This is Foo-with-star's first non-optional argument: #2%
  This is Foo-with-star's second non-optional argument: #3%
}%
\typeout{Meanings of macros related to \string\Foo}
\typeout{==================================}
\typeout{\string\Foo: \meaning\Foo}
\typeout{\name\string{Foo }: \name\meaning{Foo }}
\typeout{\string\Fooatnostar: \meaning\Fooatnostar}
\typeout{\name\string{\string\Fooatnostar}: \name\meaning{\string\Fooatnostar}}
\typeout{\string\Fooatstar: \meaning\Fooatstar}
\typeout{\name\string{\string\Fooatstar}: \name\meaning{\string\Fooatstar}}
\typeout{^^J}

\name\commander{Bar}[2]{%
  This is Bar-without-star's first non-optional argument: #1%
  This is Bar-without-star's second non-optional argument: #2%
}{%
  This is Bar-with-star's first non-optional argument: #1%
  This is Bar-with-star's second non-optional argument: #2%
}%

\typeout{Meanings of macros related to \string\Bar}
\typeout{==================================}
\typeout{\string\Bar: \meaning\Bar}
\typeout{\name\string{Bar }: \name\meaning{Bar }}
\typeout{\string\Baratnostar: \meaning\Baratnostar}
\typeout{\string\Baratstar: \meaning\Baratstar}
\typeout{^^J}

\stop
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in bracing `\csname...\endcsname` after `\newcommand`.

However, I think you can do better by avoiding `\commander` altogether. If you insist on it, you can use `xparse`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\commander}{mmo}
 {% #1 = command to define, #2 = code for the main, #3 = code for *-version
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   {
    \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{}{#2}
   }
   {
    \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{s}
     {
      \IfBooleanTF{##1}{#3}{#2}
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\commander{\foo}{This is foo, it has no *-variant}
\commander{\baz}{This is baz, normal variant}[This is baz, *-variant]

\begin{document}

\foo

\baz

\baz*

\end{document}
```

[image]